# How to construct the id of an element and perform actions on it in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my table row which is having an id `btn_number_$i`. On clicking the button I want to show the table row having id `row_$i`, which is initially hidden.

Here is my PHP code to create the two table rows:

```
echo "<tr><td>"."<button id= \"btn_number_$i\"  class='btn info toggler' >Info   <i class='icon-arrow-down'></i></button>"."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr id='row_$i' class='info_row'><td>Hello There!!</td></tr>";
```

And below is my jQuery code.
I am trying to construct the similarly named row id and perform `.show` on it. But I am not getting the desired result.

```
$(function () {
    $('.info_row').hide(); // first I need to hide all the second rows.
    $('.toggler').click(function () {
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(currentId);
        var lastChar = currentId.substr(currentId.length - 1); //Herein I am trying to extract the last character from btn_number_$i which is $i and then appending it with 'row_'
        var rowId = 'row_' + lastChar;
        console.log(rowId); // I am able to get the current value in console log.
        $('#rowId').show(); // But even after all that i am not able to show the element.
    });
});
```

Any help will be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: `'abcdefg'.split('').pop()` give you `g`.

Comment: Problem is not of not getting the last value but how to formulate the related elements id. But thanks alot its a new way to get the last element of the string, I didn't new it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the variable `rowId` containing id you constructed but using `rowId` a string literal. The selector you have will be looking element with `id = rowId`

*Change*

```
$('#rowId').show();
```

*To*

```
$('#' + rowId).show();
```

Comment: So adil $('#"another_string_literal"') is this what hindered me from getting the correct result.

Comment: You have wrong sequence of commas here $('#"another_string_literal"') it would be  $('#another_string_literal') for string constant or  $('#' + another_string_literal) for variable another_string_literal